# Filtering through a list of JQuery selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in a situation where I haven't found a selector or a selector function that quite does what I would like it to do.

Therefore I am trying to filter the list to contain only the items I would like it to.

I have a selector

```
var html = $(".foo .foobar")
```

This returns what I wanted it to.

Then I have a for loop that loops through those selected items and identifies the ones I want to keep in that list.

However, I need to keep the modified list the same type as a selector so that I can perform jquery actions to them later.

how do I create a copy of the 'html' variable (or a filtered original) but with only the desired rows that were found in the function (Keeping it still in a state as if it was a selector itself)?

Later I have an 'each' loop that begins like this:

```
html.each(function(i, el) {
   $(this).replaceWith(tempArr[i]);
```

I am trying to achieve a result where 'html.each' has 'html' as the modified list previously selected.

Thanks.

// Update

```js
var htmlTemp;

for (var primaryCounter = 0, secondryCounter = 0; primaryCounter < htmlTemp.length; primaryCounter++) {

  if (firstFound) {
    secondryCounter++;
    if (secondryCounter % columnCount === 0) {
      html.push(htmlTemp[primaryCounter]);
    }
  } else {
     if (primaryCounter === currI) {
        html.push(htmlTemp[primaryCounter]);
        firstFound = true;
     }
  }


}
```

Above is the function including the logic that I wanted to use (Which isn't going to run). Is there a way with 'filter' possibly where I can call this function and instead of 'push()' just include at these indexes found? Thanks.

Comment: This is an XY question. You're asking about how to fix your attempted solution instead of the actual problem of filtering in jQuery. To solve that, use `filter()` with whatever logic you require. We'd need to see more of your actual code (specifically the HTML and the loop you have) in order to give you a more complete example.

Comment: Can you show me an example of using filter() with a function (any function) that removes the elements at certain indexes that I found. The filter I found is based on the indexes. Thanks.

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I can't really show you any demo code as you've not shown enough of what you have for me to write the logic. I'd suggest you checkout http://api.jquery.com/filter, though.

Comment: Thank you. That filter thing will work for me. I have the logic I needed, I just didn't know how to apply it in the correct way.

Comment: I've updated the question if that helps more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `html` as an array, you can use `html.filter(callbackFunc)` to get a new list every time.

Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter